# Django graphene mutation returns Bad Request in unit test

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I have defined the following graphql schema to create an inactive user

```
from .models import User, UserManager

import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User


class PreSignupInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    email = graphene.String(required=True)
    terms_of_use = graphene.Boolean(required=True)


class PreSignup(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        pre_signup_data = PreSignupInput(required=False)

    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    def mutate(self, info, user_data=None):
        user = UserManager().create_inactive_user_with_email(user_data.email, user_data.terms_of_use)

        return PreSignup(user=user)


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    pre_signup = PreSignup.Field()
```

The **User** class is also defined as AUTH_USER_MODEL in the config and **create_inactive_user_with_email** creates an instance of User, saves it to the db and returns it.

Whenever I run the following test:

```
from graphene_django.utils.testing import GraphQLTestCase


class UserSchemaTest(GraphQLTestCase):
    def test_create_inactive_user(self):
        response = self.query(
            '''
            mutation preSignup($input: PreSignupInput!) {
                preSignup(input: $input) {
                    user {
                        id
                        email
                    }
                }
            }
            ''',
            op_name='preSignup',
            input_data={'email': 'test@example.com', 'terms_of_use': True}
        )

        print(response.json())

        self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)
```

It fails with a Bad Request error and the following error message:

```
{
    'errors': [
        {'message': 'Unknown argument "input" on field "preSignup" of type "Mutation".',
         'locations': [{'line': 3, 'column': 27}]}]
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I used [this tutorial](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/testing/) for the test.

Thank you!

Comment: There seems to be an error of matching between your `PreSignup.Arguments` fields and your `mutate` method. It should match I think

One more thing, you tell that your `PreSignupInput` is not required but you use a bang (`!` ) in your mutation query parameter.